# How to get all Grid view Values in Multi dimensional Array with out selecting or clicking any button?

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, gridview, row

I do not want to select row or to click button in grid view just to get grid view data on button control that is not in grid view control.
i am trying to get grid view values in array my code is,

GridView GV = GdItemList;
        var array = new object[GV.Rows.Count, GV.Columns.Count];

```
      for (int i = 0; i < GdItemList.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
       foreach (GridViewRow j in GdItemList.Rows)
       {
           array[j.RowIndex, j.RowIndex] = j.Cells[0];
           array[j.RowIndex, j.RowIndex+1] = j.Cells[1];
           array[j.RowIndex, j.RowIndex + 2] = j.Cells[2];
        //a.Add(gv.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text);
       }
    }
```

I am getting error

Index was outside the bound of array on line,

```
 array[j.RowIndex, j.RowIndex] = j.Cells[0];
```

when i debug it i can find grid view count 1 but here,

```
foreach (GridViewRow j in GdItemList.Rows)
```

i do not find any thing and row count is zero here

Hopes for your suggestion

Thanks

Comment: "get grid view data on button control"? For what purpose? Are you trying to transfer the values to another page?

Comment: No i want to save them in DB but i have button outside grid view on which i want to tranfer value to array

Comment: Can we see the complete handler code for the button submit?